# Add/delete input in row jquery

Tags: jquery

I have problem with below code because I want show div domain where select option **name2**. All is works when I add new and row and select option **name2** but problem is where I want hide div domain because div domain hide in all rows but I want hide in current row.

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">  
    <select id="select_register" name="service_name[0]" class="form-select">
      <option value="name1">1</option>
      <option value="name2">2</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div id="domain" class="col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="display:none;"> 
    <input type="text" name="domain_name[0]" class="form-control">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">   
    <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-success form">Add</button>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="more"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
          var counter = 1;
          $("#add").click(function () {
            var html = '';
            html += '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            html += '<select id="select_register' + [counter] + '" name="service_name[' + [counter] + ']" class="form-select">';
            html += '<option value="name1">1</option>';
            html += '<option value="name2">2</option></select>';
            html += '<div id="domain" class="col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="domain_name[' + [counter] + ']" class="form-control"></div>';
            html += '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"><button type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger form">Delete </button><br/></div></div>';
 
            $('#more_register_form').append(html);
            $(document).on('click', '#remove', function (){
                $(this).closest('.row').remove();
                counter = 1;
            }); 
 
            $(document).on('change', function () {
            var selected = $(this).val(); 
            if(selected == 'name2')
            {
                $('#domain').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#domain').hide();
            }
            counter ++; 
            });
        });
        });
```

Comment: All IDs must be unique you can't have more than one `id='domain'` change that to `class='domain'`

Comment: So how add unique ID to <div class="domain col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="display:none;"> ?

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71450280/2813224)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you must remember: **#IDs must be unique.** Every extra row added brings a duplicate `#domain`. When the browser is told to get an `#domain`, it'll find the first `#domain` and then go no further because it expects only one `#domain` exists on the page. That is the reason why only the first `#domain` works and none of the others do. So all #IDs (with one exception, explained next) are replaced by classes.

Next, a `<form>` is wrapped around everything. If there's more than one form control on the page, wrap everything in a `<form>`. There are unique behavior, terser syntax, excusive events, etc that are only possible with a `<form>`. BTW, `<form>` is the only tag with an #ID because you only need one per page and when you get tired of jQuery and use JavaScript it'll help you manage a couple of interfaces.

Use template literals when dealing with `htmlStrings` compare the syntax:

```
// Literal String - Alternating quotes from single to double is error prone
'<select name="service['+ counter +']" class="register form-select">'
// Template Literal - a ${...} is used to interpolate values
`<select name="service[${counter}]" class="register form-select">`
```

All multiple groups that were registered to an event are no longer registered. Any click on `button.delete` or change on a `select.register` is now delegated by `form#UI`. Note the second parameter designates the tag picked by the user as `this`.

```
$('#UI').on('click', '.remove', function() {...
$('#UI').on('change', '.register', function() {...
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='UI' class='container'>
    <section class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select name="service[0]" class="register form-select">
          <option selected>Register Domain</option>
          <option value="name1">1</option>
          <option value="name2">2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="domain col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="display:none;">
        <input name="domain[0]" class="form-control" placeholder='Domain Name'>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <button class="add btn btn-success float-end" type="button">Add</button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </form>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let counter = 0;
    $(".add").click(function() {
      counter++;
      html = `<section class="row"><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"><select name="service[${counter}]" class="register form-select"><option selected>Register Domain</option><option value="name1">1</option><option value="name2">2</option></select><div class="domain col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="display:none;"><input name="domain[${counter}]" class="form-control" placeholder='Domain Name'></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"><button class="remove btn btn-danger float-end" type="button">Delete</button></div></section>`;
      $('#UI').append(html);
    });

    $('#UI').on('click', '.remove', function() {
      $(this).closest('.row').remove();
    });

    $('#UI').on('change', '.register', function() {
      const selected = $(this).val();
      const row = $(this).closest('.row');
      if (selected == 'name2') {
        row.find('.domain').show();
      } else {
        row.find('.domain').hide();
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```